# How to get the number of columns when elements are floated left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

This is the reduced case:

```js
var columns = null,
  firstPositionTop = $('div').eq(0).offset().top;

$('div').each(function(index) {

  var thisPositionTop = $(this).offset().top;

  if (thisPositionTop !== firstPositionTop && columns == null) {

    columns = index;

  }

});
console.log(columns);
```

```css
div {
  width: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  margin: 5%;
  background: DeepPink;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to calculate the number of columns (4 in the above example) using JavaScript or jQuery.

Is there a simpler way?

(The number of elements will vary and there are media queries that will change the number of columns/rows).

Comment: It might help if you give a reason for getting the number of columns. Especially since you also state that their number changes with media queries.

Comment: I think you are making the wrong question. I don't know what you're trying to do, but I sure that the solution is simpler than the result of your question.

Comment: What's wrong with code show? it returns 4. You provided code but no code specific problem statement

Comment: @Pineda if it helps: with the number of columns I will change the scrollLeft to be positioned exactly in the middle of the first element. I guess I could locate the midpoint and apply it directly but I prefer to rely on the number of elements.

Comment: @charlietfl the code works but it looked to me like there must be a much simpler way I am missing (which doesn't imply creating a loop for each element, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the divs in an outer container, you could do the math on them to see how many will fit. Something like this:

```js
var oWidth = $('.outer').width();
var iWidth = $('.inner').outerWidth(true);

$('#display').text(oWidth / iWidth);
```

```css
.inner {
  width: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  margin: 5%;
  background: DeepPink;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="display"></p>
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

That being said, your initial solution works just fine, so I don't really see any reason to abandon it.

Comment: The code in the question works but I was looking for something much simpler, like this solution. If I round the number from your solution I'd have the exact value. Thank you :)